# How to delete a question using android application

Tags: support

Im trying to delete a question i had posted which has been closed but i cant find a button for deletion nor can i delete the text of the question.  I also tried flagging it for moderator intervention sonce i cant find a delete button

How can i make this thing go away so that people stop downvoting it?

Any help will be kindly appreciated

Comment: Asuming you mean [Regulators and infinite sums](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265670/regulators-and-infinite-sums), the answers have now been deleted so you should now be able to delete the question.

Comment: @JohnRennie okay.  So now how do i delete it using the android application?  My understanding is that android doesnt allow that feature

Comment: Correct. Use the web site not the Android app. You will be able to delete the question using the web site.

Comment: @JohnRennie okay.  Thank you for your kind help

Comment: This has been said earlier, but it bears repeating. If you have questions specifically about the functionality of the Android SE application, this meta site is unlikely to yield good answers (and certainly not quickly); the place to ask is [meta.se]. That said, the mobile apps are explicitly feature-limited: you have access to many, but not all, the features of the site. If you can't do something in the app, don't complain - just use the website, either the mobile version (again, feature-limited) or the desktop one. Asking endless app questions here is not productive.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty it is helping me, therefore it IS productive. If you dont like it simply ignore it. The route towards understanding is through asking questions. The OP isnt a complaint....it is a question. Evidently one cannot delete a question using android application. Thats just something that couldnt have been known without asking.

Comment: I'm not saying don't ask - I'm saying this is not really the place for app-specific questions; [meta.se] is.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty there's no way for me to know whether or not something is "app specific" unless i ask.  E.g. i didnt knowit was possible to delete a question until i asked....etc. seems reasonable enough

Answer (score 2):

You ***can not*** delete your own question when it has an up-voted answer. That question has an up-voted answer, so you ***can not*** delete it.

Comment: The comment discussion got a bit out of hand, and I don't believe it really added anything to the answer the way it was going, so I deleted it.